# php tesseract with http post no response

Tags: php, html, ocr, tesseract

I am developing an php page on the webserver.  It works in the following three steps:

1. get an image uploaded from an HTML form with POST method;
   execute tesseract to change the image into text;
2. execute tesseract to change the image into text;
3. print the text on the screen;

Now I believe the 2. and 3. steps are correct because if I use a local jpg file on the webserver, everthing works fine. However, if I use HTML form to POST an image file, no response. Any suggestion?

The HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="<webserver>/try.php">
<input type="file" name="myimg"></input>
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The try.php file on the web server

```
<?php
$im=$_FILES['myimg'];
echo exec('/usr/bin/tesseract $im stdout', $msg);
print_r($msg);
?>
```

Actually, I think the error lies in how I use the $im variable, right?

Comment: is the image committed to file? and does `www-data` (assuming this is apache) have access to read the file?

Comment: the `$im` is not a file location, its the upload variables of the file itself..  you will need to process the file first.. And then pass the pathname into the exec function..

Comment: you could use (I think) `$im['tmp_name']` as this is specific to your system so its `clean`

Comment: I have change the php code into `$im=$_FILES['myimg']['tmp_name'];`, but still no luck. Is it possible that tesseract only accept files end with .jpg or .tif ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to process the file first you can use the `'tmp_name'` path like so..

```
if(isset($_FILES['myimg'])){
echo exec('/usr/bin/tesseract '.$_FILES['myimg']['tmp_name'].' stdout', $msg);
    print_r($msg);
}
```

This MIGHT work but I have not tested..

Comment: This code still does not work. I think the main problem is that the `tmp_name` is a string without any suffix while tesseract only handle files with jpg or tif suffix.

I find a solution is to copy the `tmp_name` into `/tmp/mytmp.jpg`, then everything works fing. Is there any other way around?

Comment: @user3809822 Well then im afraid you will need to process the file first! :)

Comment: Problem solved by changing the single-quoted into double-quoted in your code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is some of my old day research about tesseract OCR.

http://amarchmike.blogspot.com/

for your question I think you missing something 
try this

```
$im="/usr/bin/tesseract/image/test00.jpg"  // change to image path
echo exec("/usr/bin/tesseract $im ");  // exec using double quote for variable representation
```

and this like to support stdout https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReleaseNotes on V3.03

Comment: Yes, for a local jpeg file, it works fine. However, what I want to do is to submit image from front end and tesseract process it in the backend.

Comment: @user3809822 Yes, so when you upload image from front end to webserver it will create temp file of your upload file and represent the path with a property up to language you used. For PHP, $_FILES['FORMNAME']['tmp_name'] = temp path.